# How can we lock an ERC20 token in a contract and generate another ERC20 token proportionally over the locked duration?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, erc-20, gnosis

> "Gnosis tokens (GNO) are the generator for Wisdom token (WIZ)
> creation.
>
> WIZ can only be created via activating the utility of the
> Gnosis (GNO) tokens. This is done via a smart contract system. The
> smart contract works as follows: GNO token holders agree to “lock”
> their tokens in a smart contract (30–365 days). A multiplier is added
> for longer lock durations.
>
> The smart contract determines the user
> selected lock duration and applies that duration to a formula that is
> designed to regulate the supply of WIZ tokens currently in use. Prior
> to locking their GNO tokens in the smart contract, users will be able
> to see exactly how much WIZ they will receive as a result of executing
> the smart contract. Once users execute the contract, 30% of their WIZ
> will be distributed for immediate use, and the remaining 70% will be
> distributed proportionally over the locked duration.
>
> Once the lock
> duration expires, the locked GNO ceases to generate WIZ and the GNO
> becomes freely transferable by the holder. There is no limit (other
> than duration) for how many times GNO tokens may be used to create
> WIZ."

How can we implement a token like WIZ (ERC20) which is generated by locking another GNO (ERC20)?

I couldn't find the official implementation of WIZ token on gnosis github page. Can anyone point to a similar implementation on these lines ?